# Google One Tap Sign in not working : [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: oauth, google-signin, sign-in-with-google

I have implemented the Google One tap sign in as specified in the docs. with the HTML Api.

Created the GCP project and have added local host to accepted origins and all required stuff.

I have tried on various browsers and cleared caches and also run on incognito mode. But still I can't get it to working

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
  data-client_id="uuu"
  data-auto_select="true"
  data-login_uri="uuu"
  data-itp_support="true"
  data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false"
  data-prompt_parent_id="g_id_onload"
  style="position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 30px; z-index: 1001;"
  data-auto_prompt="true">
</div>
```

[Google Sign in doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/choose-components)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to the fact that I had added the url: localhost:3000 but not localhost in the allowed origins section